# Log value to absolute

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am confused how to convert from log value to absolute value from the graph. Below is an example:

[image: picture]

In the graph, it shows the correlation of age of week and weight of placenta (in log). I can get the value of each dot but they are in log value. if I want to convert them into absolute, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain, but it looks like the $\log$ weights were of base 10. Since
 $ a=10^{\log(a)}$, to find your true $w$ values, simply compute $w=10^y$.

Maximum $y$ values in the graph are around 2.3, and $10^{2.3}=199.53$, which may be closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In a general case, if we have $$a = \log_b{c}$$ then $$b^a = c$$

So you have the log of the weight $w$ and in the graph, you have $\log w$. It is hard to see but it looks like the maximum value seen for the $\log w$ is at about $\log w = 2.5$.

> This is just an estimate as it is difficult to read the actual values but the same logic apply's for any value.

When we usually see $\log$ without any further info about it's base, we can take $e$ as the base and $\log$ becomes the natural logarithm.

This means we have $$\log w = 2.5$$

We can apply what I mentioned at the top:$$e^{2.5} = w$$

> Please note that we can also do this using the rules of the natural logarithm

$$e^{2.5} \approxeq 12.8$$

Comment: Thanks @MathCoder. So, you mean if we use the natural log it will be 10 power 2.5 (as Chris Bridgett said)? Then I will get around 316 which is more reasonable value for me. Tks.

Comment: Yes exactly. If you are told the value should be around that, then that may be more appropriate. It is always important to know what values you are dealing with in this type of scenario but the same logic applies to any base.